# Notepad++ regular expression - replace a part of regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, export-to-excel

I am fixing corrupted DB export to txt file, I am new to Regular expressions:

My corrupted lines can be found using Notepad++ regular expression:

```
\r\n[^"]
```

(fine line breaks followed by everything that is not " )

I need to delete these \r\n but I need to preserve the characters following it (in my data these are digits)

Desired data:

```
"USERNAME"|"Text1"|"Text2"|"Spreadsheet" (CR)(LF)
"USERNAME"|"Text1"|"Text2"|"Spreadsheet" (CR)(LF)
```

Corrupted data:

```
"USERNAME"|"Text1"|"Text2line1 - #3.50 (CR)(LF)
1 x text2line2 - #5.40 (CR)(LF)
2 x text2line3 #6.75 (CR)(LF)
|"Spreadsheet" (CR)(LF)
```

Therefore this does not work:

```
FIND: \r\n[^"]
REPLACE: [^"]
```

Because this way I would get rid of "1" and "2" and the beginning of the new line.

I will be grateful for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a minor change to the expression so that it reads `\r\n([^"])` (notice the extra `(` and `)`). This will place the match in a regex group.

Then, simply replace that by `\1`, which is the regex group you are matching in the expression above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead:

Find what: `\R(?!=[ ^"])`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.
`(?!=[ ^"])` is a zero width assertion that assumes there're no quotes after the linebreak